# build multi arch docker image for depented springboot multi module project

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have 2 spring boot multimodule projects, usually, I build the image 'mvn clean install' on project A and run project B. Now I'm trying build the buildx docker image of project B.

[image: Project Structue]